# How do I set a layout margin for a text field in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, margins

I am attempting to create margins in my text field so that when I go to type, the text isn't pressed so tightly against the edge.

I tried using this code (above viewDidLoad)

```
var insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

Then putting this in my viewDidLoad()

```
textField.layoutMargins = insets
```

I ran the program and it still looked like there were no margins. How do I implement margins in a text field in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass UITextField and implement `textRectForBounds:`. The simplest strategy is to call `super`, get the resulting rect, inset it as desired, and return it.

Here's an example result; note that the start and end of the text have considerable white space at the margin (of course the exact amount is up to you):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By creating new `UIView` with the right(your) values, you can set the padding in `UITextField`

```
textField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100))
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Comment: Hmm I'm getting an error that says UITextField has no member 'contentInset'?

Comment: It looks like that didn't work either. Is there something I need to import for this to work? (besides UIKit?)

Comment: just check updated answer, i think thats you are looking for